# How do you read a NASA .hgt file in C#?

Tags: c#

Does anybody know how to read a NASA .hgt file in C#?

Apparently the question was asked in Python here: 
[how to read NASA .hgt binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357415/how-to-read-nasa-hgt-binary-files)

Answer (score 4):

Use GDAL library (geographic data abstraction layer): it supports HGT files and it has C# binding using SWIG.

Edit: all you information you need is [here](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/).

From the [FAQ](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/faq.html):

> **The SRTM data files have names like "N34W119.hgt". What do the letters
>   and numbers refer to, and what is ".hgt" format?**
>
> Each data file covers a one-degree-of-latitude by
>   one-degree-of-longitude block of Earth's surface. The first seven
>   characters indicate the southwest corner of the block, with N, S, E,
>   and W referring to north, south, east, and west. Thus, the
>   "N34W119.hgt" file covers latitudes 34 to 35 North and longitudes
>   118-119 West (this file includes downtown Los Angeles, California).
>   The filename extension ".hgt" simply stands for the word "height",
>   meaning elevation. It is NOT a format type. These files are in "raw"
>   format (no headers and not compressed), 16-bit signed integers,
>   elevation measured in meters above sea level, in a "geographic"
>   (latitude and longitude array) projection, with data voids indicated
>   by -32768. International 3-arc-second files have 1201 columns and 1201
>   rows of data, with a total filesize of 2,884,802 bytes ( = 1201 x 1201
>   x 2). United States 1-arc-second files have 3601 columns and 3601 rows
>   of data, with a total filesize of 25,934,402 bytes ( = 3601 x 3601 x
>   2). For more information read the text file "SRTM_Topo.txt" at
>   http://edcftp.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/srtm/Readme.html

Comment: I can't use GDAL or external libraries.

Comment: Sorry, hit return... and well... anyway, is there a header in the file? How do you know the length of the file (apparently they come in two flavors)?

Comment: Also, is the file name the only way to know that coordinates of the file itself?

Comment: See my edits. Hope they help. ANd to just confirm, yes, the terrain chunk coordinates are derivable only by the file name (just checked GDAL sources).

Comment: @zetar - Why can't you use GDAL or external libraries.  If thats really is the case then write your own library to do so.