# How to read .HGT files in R

Tags: r, binary, gis, elevation, topography

I'm trying to read elevation data from NASA stored in .HGT files into R. I've checked `rgdal` library but apparently it does not read this type of file.

ps. The Stack Overflow community shows how to read this typee of file in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357415/how-to-read-nasa-hgt-binary-files) and [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810178/how-do-i-access-hgt-srtm-files-in-c), but I was looking for a pure R solution.

### **More Info on topographic data in .HGT files:**

In 2014, the topographic data generated from NASA's Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) was released globally. The resolution of SRTM data for regions outside the United States is 1 arc-second, or about 30 meters (98 feet). You can read more information  [here](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) and download the data [here](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/).

At the present moment, the data is available for these regions of the world:
[image]

Here is a description from www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/faq.html:

> The SRTM data files have names like "N34W119.hgt". What do the letters and numbers refer to, and what is ".hgt" format?
>
> Each data file covers a one-degree-of-latitude by one-degree-of-longitude block of Earth's surface. The first seven characters indicate the southwest corner of the block, with N, S, E, and W referring to north, south, east, and west. Thus, the "N34W119.hgt" file covers latitudes 34 to 35 North and longitudes 118-119 West (this file includes downtown Los Angeles, California). The filename extension ".hgt" simply stands for the word "height", meaning elevation. It is NOT a format type. These files are in "raw" format (no headers and not compressed), 16-bit signed integers, elevation measured in meters above sea level, in a "geographic" (latitude and longitude array) projection, with data voids indicated by -32768. International 3-arc-second files have 1201 columns and 1201 rows of data, with a total filesize of 2,884,802 bytes ( = 1201 x 1201 x 2). United States 1-arc-second files have 3601 columns and 3601 rows of data, with a total filesize of 25,934,402 bytes ( = 3601 x 3601 x 2). For more information read the text file "SRTM_Topo.txt" at http://edcftp.cr.usgs.gov/pub/data/srtm/Readme.html

Comment: I am able to open these files with `raster` package.

Comment: same here. `hgt <- raster("N38W112.hgt") ; image(hgt)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple using the `raster` package (thanks to the comments of @Pascal and @hrbrmstr). The `rgdal` package must be installed as well.

```
# Load libraries
  library(raster)
  library(rgdal)

# read file
  elevation <- raster("S23W044.hgt") 
# view image
  image(elevation)
```